# Unable to receive FCM push notifications, using Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had a while since push notification where working on my App I have a Firestore collection which on create new docs it triggers the SendNotification Function.

Before the function looked like this:

```
export const sendChatNotification = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chats/{chatId}').onCreate(async (snap, ctx) => {

    //In Comment OLD Way to get info data for the notification
    const token = snap.get('sendToDeviceToken'); //snap.data().sendToDeviceToken;
    const sender = snap.get('fullSenderName'); //snap.data().fullSenderName;
    const body = snap.get('message'); //snap.data().message;

const payload = {
       notification: {
            title: sender,
             body: body,
        }
     };

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
        console.log('Message Function Executed sent to device with token: ' + token + ' from sender: ' + sender + ' with message: ' + body );
    });
}
```

This worked for a bit but stopped working although in all the logs say it finish with ok status.

[image: No errors in log]

Now a College of mine told me that he had to change this code for a new function that looks like this:

```
export const sendChatNotification = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chats/{chatId}').onCreate(async (snap, ctx) => {

    //In Comment OLD Way to get info data for the notification
    const token = snap.get('sendToDeviceToken'); //snap.data().sendToDeviceToken;
    const sender = snap.get('fullSenderName'); //snap.data().fullSenderName;
    const body = snap.get('message'); //snap.data().message;


    var tokens  = [];

    tokens.push(token)

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: sender,
            body: body,
        },
        android: {
            notification: {
                channelId: "roofdeck_default",
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                title: sender,
                body: body,
            }
        },
        apns: {
            headers: {
                "apns-push-type": "alert"
            },
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    category: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
                }
            },
        },
        data: {
            postID: snap.id,
            type: "POST_TAG",
        },
        tokens: token
    }

    if (token.length > 0) {
        await fcm.sendMulticast(payload);
    }

});
```

To be complete we added this line of code after initializing the app:

```
const fcm = admin.messaging();
```

He also mentioned that for this he had to create an Android Channel so I followed a Tutorial and modified my Main in Flutter App:

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'roofdeck_default',
  'RoofDeck Notification Channel',
  description: 'This Channel is for RoofDeck Chat Notifications',
  importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('A Background Message just showed up: ${message.messageId}');
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And on the Initial Screen I add this code on Init for it to work:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    //_isIos = Platform.isIOS;
    fbm.requestPermission();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('En OnMessage: ${message.notification.body.toString()}');
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              color: Colors.blue,
              playSound: true,
              icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      //return;
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      print('En onMessageOpenedApp: ${message.notification.body.toString()}');
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(notification.title),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(notification.body),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }

      //return;
    });
    _saveToken();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Finally to have the latest token generated I save the Token to the Firestore:

```
Future<void> _saveToken() async {
    try {
      token = await fbm.getToken();
      var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (token != null && user != null) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).update({
          'token': token,
          'tokenCreatedAt': DateTime.now(),
          'platform': Platform.operatingSystem,
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Messaging(_saveToken): $e");
    }
  }
```

I tried on an iPhone Device and after 2 hours still no Notificaton received, although I see the logs of the new Cloud Function working correctly.

[image: Working new Code]

Any Ideas what is wrong why at least on iPhone is not working the notifications.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Are you using iOS emulator, if you are it will not work, beside for iOS you need to configure APN services from apple with firebase and use the apn token to send the notification

Comment: Where do I get the APN? Sorry

Comment: For iOS, you may refer to this page https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration, its quite long so, I cant give you the detail in the comment.